# Pandas: include new timestamp rows in a dataframe if condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    value                 timestamp
18.832939   2019-03-04 12:37:26 UTC
18.832939   2019-03-04 12:38:26 UTC
18.832939   2019-03-04 12:39:27 UTC
18.955200   2019-03-04 12:40:28 UTC
18.784912   2019-03-04 12:44:32 UTC
18.784912   2019-03-04 12:45:33 UTC
20.713936   2019-03-04 17:59:36 UTC
20.871742   2019-03-04 18:08:31 UTC
20.871742   2019-03-04 18:09:32 UTC
20.873871   2019-03-04 18:10:32 UTC
```

I want the following outcome, where I identify all the timestamp gaps that are bigger than 2 minutes, but less than 15 minutes (2 < t < 15):

```
    value                 timestamp
18.832939   2019-03-04 12:37:26 UTC
18.832939   2019-03-04 12:38:26 UTC
18.832939   2019-03-04 12:39:27 UTC
18.955200   2019-03-04 12:40:28 UTC
      NaN   2019-03-04 12:41:28 UTC
      NaN   2019-03-04 12:42:28 UTC
      NaN   2019-03-04 12:43:28 UTC
18.784912   2019-03-04 12:44:32 UTC
18.784912   2019-03-04 12:45:33 UTC
20.713936   2019-03-04 17:59:36 UTC
      NaN   2019-03-04 18:00:36 UTC
      NaN   2019-03-04 18:01:36 UTC
      NaN   2019-03-04 18:02:36 UTC
      NaN   2019-03-04 18:03:36 UTC
      NaN   2019-03-04 18:04:36 UTC
      NaN   2019-03-04 18:05:36 UTC
      NaN   2019-03-04 18:06:36 UTC
      NaN   2019-03-04 18:07:36 UTC
20.871742   2019-03-04 18:08:31 UTC
20.871742   2019-03-04 18:09:32 UTC
20.873871   2019-03-04 18:10:32 UTC
```

That means, I must do two things in order to achieve this goal:

1. Identify where the gaps meet the condition I want. Because we might have gaps that are even bigger than 15 minutes and I'm not interested in those.
2. Once identified, make new rows with 1 minute increases or just evenly spaced values with Timestamps.

I can make the 1st one with this:

```
df['aux_1'] = ((df['timestamp'].diff() > '0 days 00:02:00') & (df['timestamp'].diff() < '0 days 00:15:00')).astype(int) #get ending of the gap.
df['aux_2'] = df['aux_1'].shift(-1) #beginning of the gap.
df['intervals'] = df['aux_1'] + df['aux_2'] #both beginning and end with numeric consecutive flags contained in a single column.
```

But, I'm not sure how to do the second part, at least not "Pandas-like". It would be ideal to somehow identify begin-end of the timestamp interval I intend to fill, and then apply asfreq('1m'), and use that vector to fill the gaps I want. Just that not sure how to do that properly.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My suggestion would be 1) generate a dataframe with a timestamp column with an interval of 1 min. 2) join the data back into the newly created dataframe on a key : timestamp with accurate up to the minute level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very pandas like but I would do the following.

```
new_timestamp = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['aux_2']==0:
        new_timestamp.append(row['timestamp'])
    elif row['aux_2']==1:
        new_timestamp += pd.date_range(row['timestamp'], df.iloc[i+1]['timestamp'], freq='min').to_list()

new_df = df.set_index('timestamp')
new_df = new_df.loc[new_timestamp]
```

this results in

```
print(new_df)
timestamp                   value       aux_1   aux_2   intervals
2019-03-04 12:37:26+00:00   18.832939   0.0     0.0     0.0
2019-03-04 12:38:26+00:00   18.832939   0.0     0.0     0.0
2019-03-04 12:39:27+00:00   18.832939   0.0     0.0     0.0
2019-03-04 12:40:28+00:00   18.955200   0.0     1.0     1.0
2019-03-04 12:41:28+00:00   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2019-03-04 12:42:28+00:00   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2019-03-04 12:43:28+00:00   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2019-03-04 12:44:28+00:00   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2019-03-04 12:44:32+00:00   18.784912   1.0     0.0     1.0
2019-03-04 12:45:33+00:00   18.784912   0.0     0.0     0.0
2019-03-04 17:59:36+00:00   20.713936   0.0     1.0     1.0
2019-03-04 18:00:36+00:00   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2019-03-04 18:01:36+00:00   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2019-03-04 18:02:36+00:00   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2019-03-04 18:03:36+00:00   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2019-03-04 18:04:36+00:00   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2019-03-04 18:05:36+00:00   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2019-03-04 18:06:36+00:00   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2019-03-04 18:07:36+00:00   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2019-03-04 18:08:31+00:00   20.871742   1.0     0.0     1.0
2019-03-04 18:09:32+00:00   20.871742   0.0     0.0     0.0
```

Comment: This is good, I mean, I was hoping there was a way of doing this without having to set the timestamp as an index. But I can shift the column positions and set a new numeric-ascending index if I want to.Thanks for this onno!